# GWT 2.4, GWTP and Hibernate + Maven with Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, maven, gwt-platform

I'm trying to make a pom.xml for my project. This project will use GWT 2.4, GWT-Platform and Hibernate.
But, I'm not been able to put it to work. Maven simply doesn't download do GWT and other dependencies.
I'm not very accustomed with Maven, so, I think i've been making something very wrong.
I just delete my "project" and i'm wanting to start it again.

Someone managed to make it all work together some time and can, please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i got mad and delete it. But, was basically this example http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven-googlewebtoolkit2-plugin/simpledatasample/pom.xml with some modifications (gwt version, for example, and replacing hsqldb by hibernate following some example I've found somewhere. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [mojo plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) instead of the one that you have been trying. I have been using it and works perfect. If you have m2eclipse make the things much easier for you.

Comment: GWT works! but now, how I put hibernate to download all depencies? Is there a simply way to do that?

Comment: You mean make maven to download all the hibernate's dependencies? or add hibernate to the pom.xml?

Comment: Both. I even get to add hibernate, but it does not download all the dependencies...

Comment: Maven will download the dependencies for sure. You may be need to add the slf4j. In case maven does not find Hibernate you have to add the repository in your pom.xml:

<repository>
  <id>JBoss</id>
  <name>JBoss Repsitory</name>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: it works! thanks! But, I got another problem, when I add the GWTP depencies and try to use it with eclipse, eclipse put all the "overrides" in code red, saying that my overrides are wrong... any idea?

Comment: Can be two things. First one you project is using java 1.5 or less. Go the properties of your project > Java Complier and select Java 1.6.

Second possibility is your Project Facets, you can find on the properties of your project and change for java 1.6 as well.

Comment: maybe you can help me with one more thing... take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8415720/405013 thanks